# Android studio logcat conflict with forefront TMG proxy client

Tags: android-studio, proxy, adb, logcat

I have recently update android studio to Iguana | 2023.2.1 and since than I am facing issue with logcat.
I can see devices using adb devices in command prompt.
I can also see devices in android studio while running the app in emulator.
But I can`t find devices in android logcat and also no logcat is printing. After checking adea.log file for android studio I found this

```
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Error connecting channel to address '/127.0.0.1:5037'
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ConnectTask.run(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:389)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:209)
```

After further investigation and searching over internet i found that this could be a proxy or VPN issue.
As I am  also behind a corporate firewall and using forefront TMG as proxy client. Disabling TMG client didnt worked, but after un-installing TMG client I can see my device in logcat and showing all logs as expected. But the problem is I can`t uninstall TMG client as it is required to access further internal and external systems.
So I am looking for any other way to use android studio along with TMG client. Any thoughts/help?

Comment: A VPN system that affects localhost traffic would really be unexpected. As you mention the Android Studio update I assume this was working before. Updating AS doe snot mean updating adb tools, does logcat works when you execute `adb logcat` in a shell?

Comment: Yes, adb logcat  works in shell.

Comment: The socket address mentioned in the error `/127.0.0.1:5037` looks strange to me. That doesn't look like a valid socket address to me because of the slash at the beginning. May be TMG has somehow intercepted the localhost resolution and has added the slash as no scheme was present? Anyway I would contact support of TMG client as this is most likely a bug in TMG client.

Comment: May be due to this its throwing error as "that is not a socket" as shown in my question. 
But Interestingly I have managed to run both Android studio and TMG side by side after using an exe file provide by **Proxifier** developers by issue the command 
**NoLsp.exe c:\path to android studio\androidstudio.exe**
**NoLsp.exe c:\path to adb\adb.exe**
**NoLsp.exe c:\path to buildtools\buildtools.exe**
I don`t know what this exe is doing under the hood but it fixed my issue.
Here is link for Nolsp.exe thread
[Nolsp.exe link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4177#issuecomment-597736482)